# What is the optimal size of a prefix index for urls (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm collecting a few million rows of data containing URLs. To deduplicate these, I need to search for an existing URL before inserting a new row. Hence, I would like to create an index on that column.

What is the best prefix size, knowing that most URLs start with `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: The longer the better for de-duping.

Comment: I would at least make sure the domain, subdomain and top level domains are included. Including part of the URL path is also convenient. Now you won't be able to use equality searches effectively, but *Range Index Scan* instead. Make sure your code properly accounts for this.

Comment: so @GordonLinoff you would not even set a prefix, but just create an index like `CREATE INDEX idx_url ON news (source_url);` (instead of `CREATE INDEX idx_url ON news (source_url(11));` ?

Comment: @Renaud . . . If you want to de-dup and the source URL is small enough to fit in the index, then yes.  Use the full URL.  I mean, you could spend a lot of effort trying to figure out methods on _your_ data, but you would lose the ability to automatically enforce uniqueness with a constraint or index.

Answer (score 3):

For a few million rows, there is essentially no chance that `MD5(URL)` will have an accidental collision.  That's a 32 hex digits (`CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii`).  Or better would be `UNHEX(...)` and put it in `BINARY(16)`.

Then add a `UNIQUE` index on that column.

What version are you using?  Some newer version of MariaDB has something like that builtin.

Comment: I'm on MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

The are two ways to add index on long string:

1. add index for crc32(urls),just add a column named `crc32_urls` and create a index on this.It is possible some urls have same result by crc32(urls),so every time you search you should run like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE crc32_urls = xxx AND urls = xxx
```

2. use prefix index.For assuming how much prefix's length should be.You can caculate by

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT urls)/COUNT(*) FROM table
```

compared with

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT left(urls, x))/COUNT(*) FROM table
```

the `x` is length you specified.When two number is close,choose min length.